# output public ip of gateway in azure to auto create new a records in cloudfare

Tags: terraform, cloudflare

I would like to create new A records in Cloudfare using output of terraform public ip after creation. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/public_ip.html

I can output the public ip , I have also verified creation of records using cli and api with keys in cloudflare separately

Comment: So what's your question and what did you try?

Comment: I am trying to create an A record in cloudflare to add public ip of azure vm which is exported from Azure newly created vm. I would also like to add multiple cnames based on variable value passed